# How to monitor the internet at large for threats to your organization?

Tags: threat-mitigation

What are approaches for monitoring cyber threats “outside” of the organisation, such as data like account passwords, credit cards, company data for sale, etc?

While there are services for monitoring account credential availability with email, social media, cybersquatting and so on, can this be done on a much broader scale including for example monitoring below?

- catfishing principals
- spamming from your domain (or a principal’s private email)
- availability of data on a company or principals and possibly many more pieces of information
- data from information brokers and possibly criminal sources

These are just ideas. Generally, what is best practice for monitoring the internet at large regarding threats pertaining to your organization?

To be clear, this isn’t about standard practice for securing and monitoring “your” network. It’s really about getting an early warning sign that something’s been compromised or there’s been some interest at the very least.

Comment: There are some services that can help for some aspects of this (to pick a random example, monitoring for registration of domains that are simple typos of your own, or copyright violations in social media/youtube, etc...).  However in general there are too many possible things to monitor for, so the answer varies substantially from company to company (although most companies probably don't do any "external" monitoring at all)

Comment: That's a massive and broad list of different types of threats on different layers. There is not going to be a single approach or method to tackle all of that. "Look for all the bad things" is a tall order.

Comment: thank you both. I feared that when researching the topic. Also got the impression that most organizations do nothing in that direction.